# Choosing a Random File lua

Tags: lua, luvit

Well, like it says in the title I need to figure out how to choose a random file from a folder with no idea on where to start or what to look for. Anyone willing to help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of files in the folder using [lfs module](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/examples.html), store them in a table, and get a random element from that table using `t[math.random(#t)]` expression.